# CakePHP Login Form Validation from Controller Ignoring 'on' => 'create'

Tags: validation, cakephp

I have some validation in my User model that checks the email address is unique, email address is formatted as an email etc.

For the login form in particular, I do want to validate that the email field is filled out with a proper email address BUT I do not want to fire the unique rule. I tried adding 'on' => 'create' to the unique rule but all the validation still fires.

This is what I have in my model:

```
public $validate = array (
'email' => array(
'email' => array(
        'rule' => 'email',
        'required' => 'create',
        'allowEmpty' => 'false'
    ),
'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'on' => 'create',
            'message' => 'This email address already exists in the     database. Would you like to login?'
      )
);
```

And this is in the controller's login function:

```
if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('email', 'password')))) {
    // do login, redirect etc.
}
```

This is my view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Please enter your email address and password'); ?></legend>
    <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
```

How do I get cakePHP to recognize that certain validation rules should not fire for certain actions without having to "unset" rules.

And if I do wind up having to unset a rule, would I have to set it again to get it to fire where it should be firing or is the unset only good for the duration of the action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Just remove the validation `isUnique`  for email before validating the data.

These are the possible ways to remove the validation by doing unset of the validation array keys.

```
$this->User->validator()->remove('email', 'isUnique');
```

**(OR)**

```
$validator = $this->User->validator();
unset($validator['email']['isUnique']);
```

And then validate the data here.

```
if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('email', 'password')))) {
    // do login, redirect etc.
}
```

For more info you can check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#removing-rules-from-the-set) to remove the validation.

**Method 2:**

you can also do the validation as like below.

just create one function in `User model` to validate the login form like this

**User Model**

```
public function loginValidate() {
    $validate1 = array (
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'please enter email.'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'please enter password.'
        )
    );

    $this->validate = $validate1;
    return $this->validates();
}
```

**Users Controller**

```
public function login() {
   if ($this->User->loginValidate()) {
      // do login, redirect etc.
   }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the second method and it seems to work. Do I now need to set $this->validate back to $validate or will it reset itself for me on the next page?

Comment: it's setting `$this->validate` to `$validate1` when you call `loginValidate` function. `$validate` will remain same unless and until you call `loginValidate`